# Histogram with double bars

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I would like to plot a histogram that shows the mean of the columns 'amb_o', 'intel_o', 'sinc_o', 'fun_o', 'attr_o', 'sinc_o' across the 'match' column. So for match(1) vs no match(0) I would like to see the mean of 'amb_o' next to each other, and same with the other 5 columns. In other words, I want to see the average rating across the 6 attributes for the dates that ended up in a match, vs the dates that ended up without a match. How can I do this?

(this data is from a speed dating experiment in which participants rated their dates from 0 - 10 on attributes like ambition, intelligence, sincerity, etc)

```
matchesdf = (dating.filter(['amb_o','intel_o','sinc_o','fun_o','attr_o','shar_o', 'match']))

# example of dataframe

dating = pd.DataFrame({'amb_o': [7, 8, 5], 
                       'intel_o': [5, 9, 2], 
                       'sinc_o': [8, 9, 2], 
                       'fun_o': [6, 9, 5], 
                       'match': [0, 1, 1]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. calculate the means
2. manipulate row and column multi indexes to get data set
3. plot()

```
dating = pd.DataFrame({'amb_o': [7, 8, 5], 
                       'intel_o': [5, 9, 2], 
                       'sinc_o': [8, 9, 2], 
                       'fun_o': [6, 9, 5], 
                       'match': [0, 1, 1]})

dfa = (dating
     .groupby("match")
     .agg({c:"mean" for c in dating.columns if c!="match"})
)
dfa.columns.set_names("cat",inplace=True)
(dfa
    # bring match as part of row multi-index
    .unstack().to_frame()
     # rows to columns for plot
    .T
    .plot(kind="hist")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I'd like to mean to be the y-axis, column names like 'amb_o' etc to be the x-axis. The color should be match (1) no match (0)

Comment: I don't need the frequency. Any idea how to adjust it?

Comment: histogram means you get frequency,  if you don't want frequency and want a horizontal plot change `kind="barh"`